# Adding cmidrules to pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table that I want to plot, and to print as a table using `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`. The table has multiple columns that could be grouped by a category.
While I am happy to do the grouping manually, without `cmidrules` it becomes hard to tell where the border between the categories is.

Is there a more elegant solution than `every row no <X>/.style={after row=\cmidrule{1-2}}`? (I.e. can this be added in the `table.dat`)

Here a screenshot to clarify: left is what I can get, right is what I want

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
%throughput = GHz
%frequency  = GHz
number          mode
    .137000000  {32 bit simplex}
    .539000000  \multirow{3}{*}{64 bit simplex}
   1.000000000  {}
   2.130000000  {}
   5.007000000  \multirow{3}{*}{x16 duplex}
   6.000000000  {}
   9.000000000  {}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{\textbf{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={number, mode},
    columns/number/.style={%
        column type={S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}, string type
    }, 
    columns/mode/.style={
        string type, column type={l}
    },
    precision=0,%, fixed zerofill
    outfile = debug.dat
]{table.dat}
\end{document}
```

Desired table:

```
\begin {tabular}{S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]l}%
\toprule \textbf {number}&\textbf {mode}\\\midrule %
.137000000&32 bit simplex\\%
\cmidrule{1-2}
.539000000&\multirow {3}{*}{64 bit simplex}\\%
1.000000000&\\%
2.130000000&\\%
\cmidrule{1-2}
5.007000000&\multirow {3}{*}{x16 duplex}\\%
6.000000000&\\%
9.000000000&\\\bottomrule %
\end {tabular}%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Sorry for the long wait, here is the thingy with the dummy column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
%throughput = GHz
%frequency  = GHz
   number          mode   dummy 
    .137000000  {32 bit simplex} \pfft
    .539000000  \multirow{3}{*}{64 bit simplex} {}
   1.000000000  {} {}
   2.130000000  {} \pfft
   5.007000000  \multirow{3}{*}{x16 duplex} {}
   6.000000000  {} {}
   9.000000000  {} {}
\end{filecontents*}

\def\pfft{\empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column
    name}{{\textbf{#1}}},
}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
typeset cell/.append code={%
\ifx#1\pfft%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\ \midrule}%
\fi
    },%<-added
    columns={number, mode,[index]2},
    columns/number/.style={%
        column type={S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}, string type
    }, 
    columns/mode/.style={
        string type, column type={l}
    },
    columns/dummy/.style={string type,column name={}},
    precision=0,%, fixed zerofill
    outfile = debug.dat
]{table.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you really want to manually insert it, you do not need any of the stuff below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
%throughput = GHz
%frequency  = GHz
number          mode
    .137000000  {32 bit simplex}
   \midrule .539000000  \multirow{3}{*}{64 bit simplex}
   1.000000000  {}
   2.130000000  {}
   \midrule 5.007000000  \multirow{3}{*}{x16 duplex}
   6.000000000  {}
   9.000000000  {}
\end{filecontents*}

\def\pfft{\empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{\textbf{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={number, mode},
    columns/number/.style={%
        column type={S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}, string type
    }, 
    columns/mode/.style={
        string type, column type={l}
    },
    precision=0,%, fixed zerofill
    outfile = debug.dat
]{table.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just add `every nth row={3[+1]}{before row=\midrule},` to the options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
%throughput = GHz
%frequency  = GHz
number          mode
    .137000000  {32 bit simplex}
    .539000000  \multirow{3}{*}{64 bit simplex}
   1.000000000  {}
   2.130000000  {}
   5.007000000  \multirow{3}{*}{x16 duplex}
   6.000000000  {}
   9.000000000  {}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{\textbf{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[every nth row={3[+1]}{before row=\midrule}, %<-added
    columns={number, mode},
    columns/number/.style={%
        column type={S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}, string type
    }, 
    columns/mode/.style={
        string type, column type={l}
    },
    precision=0,%, fixed zerofill
    outfile = debug.dat
]{table.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you have different multirows, you may want to trigger the `\midrule` by something. You can replace `\pfft` by whatever, it is just a placeholder for a trigger that says "do something after this row".

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
%throughput = GHz
%frequency  = GHz
number          mode
    .137000000  {32 bit simplex}
    .539000000  \multirow{3}{*}{64 bit simplex}
   1.000000000  {}
   2.130000000  {\pfft}
   5.007000000  \multirow{3}{*}{x16 duplex}
   6.000000000  {}
   9.000000000  {}
\end{filecontents*}

\def\pfft{\empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{\textbf{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[typeset cell/.append code={%
\ifx#1\pfft%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\ \midrule}%
\fi
    },%<-added
    %every nth row={3[+1]}{before row=\midrule}, 
    columns={number, mode},
    columns/number/.style={%
        column type={S[round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}, string type
    }, 
    columns/mode/.style={
        string type, column type={l}
    },
    precision=0,%, fixed zerofill
    outfile = debug.dat
]{table.dat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. I am looking at the second case, manualy inserting `\pfft`. However, I would have to insert `\pfft`after the  first row with data (`{32 bit simplex}\pfft`). This does not trigger the midrule insertion, as `string+macro != macro`, I tried adapting your example using`IfSubStr, however I either get a `Use of IfSubStr doesn't mathc its definition` error (`\IfSubStr{#1}{pfft}{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\ \midrule}}{}`) or an `illegal parameter number` error if I use `{##1}` instead.

Comment: @ted OK, if you want to manually insert this, then you do not need any of these, please have a look at my update.

Comment: I first thought this to be a brilliant solution, but there is a catch: to my understanding this  works on the assumption that I can prepend `\midrule` to the first column of my table. However, I generate a graph based on the first column of the table. For obvious reasons, this throws the parser of. So unfortunately I can't simply prepend `\midrule` to the first column. However, the mode column is only used in the table, so adding a macro there works fine. Is it possible to adjust the `\pfft` macro detection solution?

Comment: @ted I am sorry, I do not understand what precisely the problem is. What precisely do you parse? And why does your parser not struggle with the `\multirow`s? (I mean if it can deal with those, shouldn't it be possible to let it deal with `\midrule`s as well?)

Comment: it is the `pgfplots` parser my actual table has several columns, to explain this lets just add a column x. I use pgfplots to plot columns `x` and `number`. Additionally I use pgfplotstable to create a table based on `number`,`x` and `mode` in that order. As pgfplots does not have to deal with the `mode` column I can insert any text. However, the number column must be parseable as a number for `pgfplots`. unfortunately `number` happens to be the first column in my table. Adding `\midrule` to the `mode` column which is not the first column does not work.

Comment: @ted I see. Would it help to add a dummy column that is neither parsed not typeset? (I do actually not think that the `\pfft` solution is too failsafe.)

Comment: sounds good to me. I am especially interested since you say it is not typeset, as I was worried that blindly adding an empty column in front of the table might add a tiny amount of whitespace on the left side of the table.

Comment: @ted OK, I posted something...

Comment: sorry it took me forever to mark this nice answer as accepted, I somehow missed that... :/